# Error when overriding _add_ and _radd_ in python

Tags: python, overriding, addition

When I try to override _add_ and _radd_ like this:

```
class adding():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a

    def _add_(self,x):
        self.a += x
    def _radd_(self,x):
        self.a += x
```

I get an error when I try the following:

```
adding(1) + 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'adding' and 'int'
```

Does anyone know where I go wrong?

I want to update the self.a value with + x

Edit:

```
def _add_(self,x):
    return adding(self.a + x)
def _radd_(self,x):
    return adding(self.a + x)
```

throws the same error.

Comment: Nothing *magical* about `_add_`. You want `__add__`

Comment: God I forgot one of those. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: You should comment this so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To overload the `+` sign, we will need to implement `__add__()`
>   function in the class. With great power comes great responsibility. We
>   can do whatever we like, inside this function. But it is sensible to
>   return a Point object of the coordinate sum.

[ref](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operator-overloading)

You must use `__add__`:

```
def __add__(self,x):
```

Comment: Did I not do that?

Comment: __ != _ :) You must use double underscore!